# Which Inlet Barrier Filter (IBF) is used in Airbus H145?

Tags: helicopter, airbus, inlet

Inlet barrier filter (IBF) is an optional equipment in H145 / MBB-BK 117 / EC145 helicopters, which company Inlet Barrier Filters are used on them Donaldson, Aerometals etc..

The H145 Helionix / BK117 D2 Differences Training Course (airbus.com/content/dam/channel-specific/website-/us/training/…) mentions the Inlet Barrier Filter as an optional equipment, but The Airbus Options Catalogue for 2019 doesn't list an Inlet Barrier Filter for that aircraft.

The only IBF listed is for the AS350/H125 family

Answer (score 1):

The [Airbus Options Catalogue for 2019](https://www.airbus.com/content/dam/channel-specific/website-/us/stc/AHNA-Options-Catalogue.pdf) doesn't list an Inlet Barrier Filter for that aircraft.

The only IBF listed is for the AS350/H125 family

Comment: The H145  Helionix / BK117 D2 Differences Training Course (https://www.airbus.com/content/dam/channel-specific/website-/us/training/technician-courses/h145-helionix/H145%20Differences_POI.pdf) mentions the Inlet Barrier Filter as an optional equipment.

Comment: Indeed it does, but Airbus don't list one in their optional equipment catalogue. I suggest you ask them to clarify.

Comment: Thanks CatchAsCatchCan